# Docker-kompose throws "mount destination not absolute" if volume moved into dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have tried moving volume mounts into Dockerfile like so

```
...
VOLUME log_volume:/var/log/myapp
...
```

And the docker compose yaml now looks like

```
version: '3'

services:
  rabbitmq:
    ...

  test_worker:
    image: testing_image:latest
    container_name: testapp_test_worker
    restart: unless-stopped
    stop_grace_period: 3m
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-file: "5"
        max-size: "10m"
    env_file:
      - test_app_env_file
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq

volumes:
  log_volume:
```

Previously, the volume was declared in the yaml, and the service worked. After moving it to Dockerfile (well, the image), it now crashes with the error message:

> Cannot start service test_worker: OCI runtime create failed: invalid mount {Destination:log_volume Type:bind Source:/var/lib/docker/volumes/e4b9d8e71a335cd6a8b2125a91b891424afddc6d0fe7af9340a397204bb6ec5d/_data Options:[rbind]}: mount destination log_volume not absolute: unknown

I i'm using docker engine v20.10.7 and docker for windows 3.5.1.

And just in case - the application worked fine before. I am now trying to move more stuff into dedicated docker images, it only broke after moving the volume inside.

Comment: In a Dockerfile you can't specify _what_ to mount in a `VOLUME`, only that a given directory should always have a volume mounted on it.  (What should happen if you just `docker run` this image, without the Compose setup?)  For many cases you don't want `VOLUME` in your Dockerfile at all since it's not necessary to mount a host directory and since it has confusing side effects.

Comment: I was following this as an example https://gitlab.com/mostwanted002/intel-owl-gke/-/blob/master/dockerfile-celery-worker If it doesn't work like that, can you elaborate as to how this usecase functiosn?

Comment: Delete the `VOLUME` line in your Dockerfile.  The best setup is to configure your application to log to its stdout, in which case `docker logs` will collect the logs; if you can't do that, you can put `volumes:` in the `docker-compose.yml` file to mount a host directory for the log path.  But you cannot specify in the image itself that a specific host directory or named volume will be used (many Compose options cannot be specified in a Dockerfile).

Comment: AS per the url i sent earlier. Does this work with kubernetes? Or is the dockerfile i sent in the gitlab url erronous?

Comment: The `VOLUME` directive only takes a container path and you cannot include a host directory name or volume name in it; the syntax you show is incorrect.  What you're proposing in that Dockerfile won't work well in Kubernetes since it's hard to share volumes between pods and it's tricky to read back the contents of a volume.